# How to check if card pin have been used?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a student result portal and I want each pin to one student for 5 times. 
Here is my code:

```
if (!$error) {
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * from pin WHERE userid='$reg'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($res); // if regno correct it returns must be 1 row
    if( $count == 1 && $row['userid']==$reg ) {
        $pinid = $row['id'] ;
        $check_hw = $row['hw'] ;
        if ($check_hw <=4 ) {
            $res=mysql_query("UPDATE pin SET userid='$reg',status='1',hw=hw+1 WHERE pin='$pin'");

            $_SESSION['user'] = $row['userid'];
            header("Location: access.php");
        } else {
            $errMSG = "Card Limit Exceeded";
        }
    } else {
        $errMSG = "Card Used By Another user Or Limit Exceeded";
    }
}
```

this what i want to do please help

if(user enter pin){
    select status from pins where pin = pin
        if(status = "used" or pin is tied to a different ID other that the student ID entered){
                echo " card used and buy new scratch card  "
                 header('Location: buypin.php');
           }
       else{
                  header('Location: rightplace.php');
                  set the status of this pin to "used" and tie that very pin to the students ID
              }

}
i did rewrite the code to

if (!$error) {

```
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT id,userid,hw FROM pin WHERE userid=" . (int)$reg);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($res); // if regno correct it returns must be 1 row

         if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            $pinid = $row['id'] ;
            $check_hw = $row['hw'] ;
            if ($check_hw <=4 ) {
            $res=mysql_query("UPDATE pin SET userid='$reg',status='1',hw=hw+1 WHERE pin='$pin'");


               $_SESSION['user'] = $row['userid'];
            header("Location: access.php");

            }

                 else {
            $errMSG = "Card Limit Exceeded";
        }
        } else {
            $errMSG = "Card Used By Another user ";
        }


    }
```

my working code

if( isset($_POST['btn-signup']) ){

```
$reg = trim($_POST['reg']);
    $reg = strip_tags($reg);
    $reg = htmlspecialchars($reg);

    $pin = trim($_POST['pin']);
    $pin = strip_tags($pin);
    $pin = htmlspecialchars($pin);


$res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pin WHERE pin ='$pin'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$check_id = $row['userid'];
    // checking if the colum userid is empty 
    if ('' !== $row['userid']){    
       // if userid colum is not empty,reg no is correct and limit more than 4
       if ($row['userid']==$reg && $row['hw']<=4) {
            $errMSG = "log";

            }else {
            $errMSG = " Card Used Or  Limit Exceeded";
    }
    }else{

$errMSG = "log";


          }
```

}

?>
Thanks alot

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_` functions, upgrade to `mysqli_` and if you are using user-suppplied data in your query, use prepared statements with placeholders and bound variables.  If you only want `userid`, don't use `*`.

Comment: I'm not certain that `$errMSG = "Card Used By Another user Or Limit Exceeded";` is accurate feedback.  How could `$row['userid']==$reg` possibly be `false`?  I think you might want to use: `"SELECT id, hw FROM pin WHERE userid=" . (int)$reg`  Then `if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {` (don't bother with `num_rows()`))

Comment: Can a user have multiple pins?  Each pin can be used upto 5 times, right?  Do you need a two-part check in the first query (userid and pin)?

Comment: `$row['userid']==$reg` this is superfluous as it's in the SQL where clause so can only exist if that is already true. Can num rows be more than 1? If so then using `== 1` will not work.

Comment: thanks. i want to check from tbpin where pin=reg and check if the a user with a reg=reg have used pin. i was just looking for way to check if a pin have been used by a particular user using the concept of user login procedure. please can u help with a better approach to check the two table

Comment: i did rewrite the code like this